# How to build gcc-6.x.0 on x64 without "unknown spec" complain?

Tags: gcc

I followed steps described in [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/gcc.html), but stuck at

```
g++ -fno-PIE -c  -DIN_GCC_FRONTEND -g -O2 -DIN_GCC     -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/. -I../../gcc/../include -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include -I/opt/third/gmp-6.1.2/include -I/opt/third/mpfr-3.1.5/include -I/opt/third/mpc-1.0.3/include  -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libbacktrace   -o cc1-checksum.o -MT cc1-checksum.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/cc1-checksum.TPo cc1-checksum.c
g++    -g -O2 -DIN_GCC     -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -o cc1 c/c-lang.o c-family/stub-objc.o attribs.o c/c-errors.o c/c-decl.o c/c-typeck.o c/c-convert.o c/c-aux-info.o c/c-objc-common.o c/c-parser.o c/c-array-notation.o c/c-fold.o c-family/c-common.o c-family/c-cppbuiltin.o c-family/c-dump.o c-family/c-format.o c-family/c-gimplify.o c-family/c-indentation.o c-family/c-lex.o c-family/c-omp.o c-family/c-opts.o c-family/c-pch.o c-family/c-ppoutput.o c-family/c-pragma.o c-family/c-pretty-print.o c-family/c-semantics.o c-family/c-ada-spec.o c-family/c-cilkplus.o c-family/array-notation-common.o c-family/cilk.o c-family/c-ubsan.o i386-c.o glibc-c.o \
      cc1-checksum.o libbackend.a main.o libcommon-target.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a   ../libbacktrace/.libs/libbacktrace.a ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a   -L/opt/third/gmp-6.1.2/lib -L/opt/third/mpfr-3.1.5/lib -L/opt/third/mpc-1.0.3/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp -rdynamic -ldl  -lz
g++: fatal error: unknown spec function ‘gt’
```

To be specific, it was built on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu with gmp-6.1.2, mpc-1.0.3 and mpfr-3.1.5.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely in some environmental variables of your session. You can try to run the make command in a clean environment:

```
env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin make
```

Comment: Yes, it is due to environment. However, the process is not very predictable or repeatable. Even with SAME clean env, the compilation may fail or ok by chance. Anyway I finally built it.

Comment: In my case, the environment variable at fault was LPATH; it was overriding any -L directive used to find the libraries and, apparently, spec files.